# Does a Bounded linear transformation from a Banach space to Real numbers map a bounded closed set to a closed set?

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, linear-transformations, banach-spaces

Specifically I need to know that whether a bounded linear transformation from the sequence space l_1 to Real numbers map the closed unit sphere to a closed set?
I'm thinking of this problem for two days. I'll be thankful for any help

Comment: What did you tried?

Comment: I tried to use theorems like open mapping theorem. Nothing worked. Do you think the result is true? Or can you please give a counter example?

Comment: **Big hint**: The result is not true.

Comment: Please give a counter example

Comment: Have you try finding one first?  What sort of examples have you tried?

Comment: Specifically I need to check this result for a continuous linear map from sequence space with 1- norm (l^1) to Real numbers. I didn't get a counter example here. Please give me a counter example under these settings

Comment: Please add that extra assumption in the question (you can edit the post)

Comment: @Arctic Chat, I have editted my question as you told. I'm using my mobile that's why I'm not able to type math symbols properly. Due to Covid, I can't go my university.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $T(x_n)=\sum (1-\frac 1 n) x_n$ for all $(x_n) \in \ell^{1}$. Note that $|T(x_n)| \leq 1$ for all $(x_n)$ in the closed unit ball.  Since $Te_n=1-\frac 1 n$ it follows that the supremum of the image of the unit ball is $1$. I will let you  check that this supremum is never attained. Hence the image is not closed.

Comment: I didn't understand the map, I think it gives the image of a subset of l^1 written as a sequence. For example  T(e_1) = 1, T(e_2) = 1/2, T(e_3) = 1/3,... But what are the images of other elements in the space? Since l^1 is uncountable we can't write the entire space as a sequence. Please explain little more

Comment: You are not required to find out all elements of $T(C)$ to show that it is not closed. You have already discovered that $\frac  1n (=Te_n)$ belongs to $T(C)$ for every $n$. If $T(C)$ is closed then $0$ would belong to it because $0$ is the limit of the numbers $\frac 1 n$. But $T(x_n)=0$ would mean $\sum \frac {x_n} n=0$. Since $x_n \geq 0$ this implies $x_n=0$ for all $n$. But then the condition $\sum x_n=1$ is violated. Hence $0$ is not in $T(C)$.

Comment: @AbdulJaleel The definition of $T(x_n)$ applies to all elements $(x_n)$ of $\ell^{1}$ not just elements of the  set $C$.

Comment: But to define a map (here a linear map) we need to ensure the images of all elements. For example as you told if T(e_n) = 1/n,  what is the image (1/2, 0,0,0,...) Which is not a term in the sequence (e_n)

Comment: @AbdulJaleel My answer was not correct for the edited version of your question. So I have revised my answer.